# Domination algorithm in graphs

Tags: graph

I'm working on a project, on an app, that can visualize undirected graphs and show on this domination algorithm. There are some examples:

[image: Dominating graphs]

I have some open questions about programmable solution of this problem.
I use lists to store vertices of generated graph, but I do not know how can I store edges, that connects the dominated vertices? Like how should I store edges in example C? 2 red vertices dominating all others.

Comment: Did you take a look at [the standard representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29#Representations)?

Comment: Generally, either you use an adjacency list/matrix, or you use a container of pairs of points. Do you need help choosing between these options, or understanding the options, or is there something about this "domination algorithm" that constrains what representations would be acceptable?

Comment: The used graph generation algorithm works with lists. So graph's data is stored already. I can't know how to represent dominating data, how to work with this algorithm in Java.